# Error: expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: 'item[1]' must not be empty

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I'm using the code below. What I'm trying to do is pick up a parameter with a fullfillment on Dialogflow, then use that in a response to the user. That works, but I do not see the suggestion and I get the error below (in the simulator) What have I done wrong?

I also get this error:

```
MalformedResponse
expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: 'item[1]' must not be empty.
```

This is my code:

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
//const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {
  dialogflow,
  BasicCard,
  BrowseCarousel,
  BrowseCarouselItem,
  Button,
  Carousel,
  Image,
  LinkOutSuggestion,
  List,
  MediaObject,
  Suggestions,
  SimpleResponse,
 } = require('actions-on-google');


process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));


  function emojify(agent) {
    let conv = agent.conv();


    conv.ask("Test response:" + request.body.queryResult.parameters.sentence);
    conv.ask(new Suggestions('The cat likes fish'));


    agent.add(conv);


  }

  // Run the proper function handler based on the matched Dialogflow intent name
  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Emojify', emojify);

  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you invoking the action?

Comment: @MatejMecka Using an intent in Dialogflow

Comment: Any luck with this issue ?

Comment: Nope, still the same @N Jay

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from what you called in conv.ask.
I think with your showed result that it's from the line

```
conv.ask(new Suggestions('The cat likes fish'));
```

Try like this:

```
conv.ask(new Suggestions(['The cat likes fish']));
```

Because this is how I used it on my program.
It is doesn't come from here then it's from

```
conv.ask("Test response:" + request.body.queryResult.parameters.sentence);
```

Where it doesn't contain only your string... try printing it.

Comment: Sorry, neither worked. I did the brackets and removed the parameter. Same error.

Comment: Could you try replacing your two conv.ask by one simple conv.ask with a string to see if you still get the error ?

Comment: What you did should work so maybe firstly try with only your text without the suggestions. For more information you should have some log somewhere that contains the JSON of your response and you should compare it with the available doc for v2